# Define a new monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading, monads

I would like to create my own monad in Haskell, and have Haskell treat it just like any other built in monad. For instance, here is code for creating a monad that updates some global state variable each time it is called, along with an evaluator that uses it to compute the number of times the `quot` function is called:

```
-- define the monad type
type M a = State -> (a, State)
type State = Int

-- define the return and bind operators for this monad
return a x = (a, x)
(>>=) :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
m >>= k = \x -> let (a,y) = m x in
                let (b,z) = k a y in
                (b,z)

-- define the tick monad, which increments the state by one
tick :: M ()
tick x = ((), x+1)

data Term = Con Int | Div Term Term
-- define the evaluator that computes the number of times 'quot' is called as a side effect
eval :: Term -> M Int
eval (Con a)   = Main.return a
eval (Div t u) = eval t Main.>>= \a -> eval u Main.>>= \b -> (tick Main.>>= \()->Main.return(quot a b))

answer :: Term
answer = (Div (Div (Con 1972)(Con 2))(Con 23))

(result, state) = eval answer 0

main = putStrLn ((show result) ++ ", " ++ (show state))
```

As implemented now, `return` and `>>=` belong in the namespace `Main`, and I have to distinguish them from `Prelude.return` and `Prelude.>>=`. If I wanted Haskell to treat `M` like any other type of monad, and properly overload the monad operators in `Prelude`, how would I go about that?

Comment: Typeclasses are explained well in the online book [learnYouAHaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads). The linked section deals with making monads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make your new monad work with all the existing Haskell machinery--`do` notation, for instance--all you need to do is declare your type an instance of the `Monad` typeclass. Then the `Prelude` functions `>>=`, `return`, etc. will work with your new type just as they do with all other `Monad` types.

There's a limitation, though, that will require some changes in your examples. Type synonyms (declared with `type`) cannot be made class instances. (Your `M a` is *exactly the same as* `Int -> (a, Int)`.) You'll need to use `data` or `newtype` instead.  (The distinction between those two is not relevant here.)

Both of those keywords create a genuinely new type; in particular, they create a new *data constructor*. You should read up on this in any fundamental Haskell text. Briefly, `newtype X a = Y (...)` creates a new *type* `X a`; you can *create* values of that type using the constructor `Y` (which can, and often does, have the same name as the type constructor `X`); and you can *consume* values by pattern matching on `Y`. If you choose not to export the data constructor `Y`, only functions in your module will be able to manipulate the values directly.

(There's a GHC extension `TypeSynonymInstances` but it won't help you here, because of a separate issue: type synonyms cannot be partially applied; for any `type X a = {- ... -}` you can only write `X a` or `X Int` or whatnot, never just `X`. You can't write `instance Monad M` because `M` is partially applied.)

After that, all you need to do is move your definitions of `return` and `>>=` into an `instance Monad` declaration:

```
newtype M a = M (State -> (a, State))

instance Monad M where
  return a = M $ \x -> (a, x)
  m >>= k = {- ... -}
```

Note that the implementation of `(>>=)` is slightly verbose because you need to unwrap and rewrap the `newtype` using its data constructor `M`. Look at [the implementation of `StateT` in `transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#State), which uses a record accessor to make it easier. (You can manually write a function `runM :: M -> State -> (a, State)` equivalent to the record syntax that `transformers` and many other packages use.)

Comment: Would this work with `newtype M a = (State -> (a, State))` as well, or is `newtype` in some way different from `type` so that adding the `M` on the right hand side is necessary?

Comment: @DavidPfau `newtype` is different.  You have to explicitly wrap and unwrap things using the `M` constructor because you are creating a new type that will not type-check as the wrapped type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation:

```
    -- Otherwise you can't do the Applicative instance.
    import Control.Applicative


    -- Simple function
    foo :: String -> String
    foo x = do
        x ++ "!!!"

    -- Helper for printing Monads
    print2 :: (Show a) => MyBox a -> IO()
    print2 (MyBox x) = print x


    -- Custom type declaration
    data MyBox a = MyBox a


    -- MyBox functor
    instance Functor MyBox where  
        fmap f (MyBox x) = MyBox (f x)


    -- MyBox Applicative 
    instance Applicative MyBox where  
        pure = MyBox 
        (MyBox f) <*> x = f <$> x


    -- MyBox Monad
    instance Monad MyBox where  
        return x = MyBox x
        MyBox x >>= f  = f x 

    -- (MyBox as a functor) Use a function with a wrapped value
    result1 = foo <$> (MyBox "Brian")

    -- (MyBox as an Applicative) Use a wrapped function with a wrapped value
    result2 = (MyBox foo) <*> (MyBox "Erich")

    -- (MyBox as a Monad)  Use a wrapped value with a lambda (it can be chainable)
    myLambda1 = (\ x -> MyBox (x ++  " aaa"))
    myLambda2 = (\ x -> MyBox (x ++  " bbb"))
    myLambda3 = (\ x -> MyBox (x ++  " ccc"))
    result3 = (MyBox "Rick") 
        >>= myLambda1
        >>= myLambda2
        >>= myLambda3


    -- Another Monad syntax
    result4 = do
        x <- MyBox "A" 
        y <- MyBox "B"  
        z <- MyBox "C"  
        MyBox (x ++ y ++ z)


    main = do
        print2(result1) -- "Brian!!!"
        print2(result2) -- "Erich!!!"
        print2(result3) -- "Rick aaa bbb ccc"
        print2(result4) -- "ABC"
```